# ¿Cómo obtener los distintos objetos serializados a un fichero en Java?

Tags: java, serialización

Estoy haciendo unas pruebas de **serialización de objetos**.

Mi intención era crear dos objetos, almacenarlos en un fichero de texto y posteriormente leerlos y  mostrar una propiedad de cada uno de los objetos inicialmente almacenados.

Creo que solo estoy guardando el último objeto, o si guardó los dos, leyendo el último objeto. Creo recordar que usaba un ***ArrayList*** para este tipo de operaciones...

Trazado de la ejecución:

> ```
> Creando objetos...
> Almacenando objetos...
> Writting Object...
> Almacenada persona 1
> Writting Object...
> Almacenada persona 2
> Recuperando objetos...
> Reading Object...
> Reading Object...
> Recuperado: San Pito
> Recuperado: San Pito
> ```

Código de la clase a serializar:

```
package serializacion;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Persona implements Serializable {

    String nombre;
    int edad;

    // serialVersionUID
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public Persona(String nom, int edat) {
        super();
        this.nombre = nom;
        this.edad = edat;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }
    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }

} //class
```

Código de la clase que almacena y recupera los objetos:

```
package serializacion;
import java.io.*;

public class FileHandler {

    private static String filePath = "store.txt";

    /**
     * Writes an object into a textfile
     *
     * @param  obj
     * @return boolean
     */
    public static boolean write( Object obj ) {
        System.out.println( "Writting Object..." );
        boolean response = false;

        try {
            //Abrir fichero
            File f = new File( filePath );

            //Crear stream de escritura para el fichero
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream( f );

            //Crear stream para escribir el objeto
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream( fos );


            //Escribir el objeto en el stream
            oos.writeObject( obj );

            //Escritura correcta
            response = true;

            //Cerrar streams
            oos.close();
            fos.close();

        } catch ( IOException ioe ) {
            System.err.println(
                "ERR -> Sending object. \n" + ioe.toString( ));
        }

        return response;
    }

    /**
     * Gets a writed object
     *
     * @return Object
     */
    public static Object get() {
        System.out.println( "Reading Object..." );
        Object obj = null;

        try {
            //Abrir fichero
            File f = new File( filePath );

            //Crear stream de lectura para el fichero
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream( f );

            //Crear stream para leer el objeto
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream( fis );


            //Leer el objeto en el stream
            obj = (Object) ois.readObject();

            //Cerrar streams
            ois.close();
            fis.close();

        } catch ( IOException | ClassNotFoundException ioe ) {
            System.err.println(
                "ERR -> Sending object. \n" + ioe.toString( ));
        }

        return obj;
    }

} //class
```

Clase de pruebas:

```
package serializacion;

class RunTest {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {

        System.out.println( "Creando objetos..." );
        Persona p1 = new Persona( "Luis", 23 );
        Persona p2 = new Persona( "San Pito", 34);


        System.out.println( "Almacenando objetos..." );
        boolean flag = false;
        if ( FileHandler.write( p1 )) {
            System.out.println( "Almacenada persona 1" );
            flag = true;

        } else {
            System.out.println( "ERR almacenando persona 1" );
        }

        if ( FileHandler.write( p2 )) {
            System.out.println( "Almacenada persona 2" );
            flag = true;

        } else {
            System.out.println( "ERR almacenando persona 2" );
        }


        if ( flag ) {
            System.out.println( "Recuperando objetos..." );

            Persona r1 = (Persona) FileHandler.get();
            Persona r2 = (Persona) FileHandler.get();

            System.out.println( "Recuperado: " + r1.getNombre( ));
            System.out.println( "Recuperado: " + r2.getNombre( ));
        } else
            System.err.println( "Sin objetos en fichero." );
    }

} //class
```

Answer (score 1):

Estás serializando los dos objetos. El problema es que serializas el primer objeto en el fichero `store.txt`, y luego sobreescribes ese fichero al serializar el segundo objeto.

Posibles soluciones:

- Un fichero distinto para cada objeto (pasar el nombre del fichero por parámetro).
- "Empaquetar" todos los objetos en otro `Serializable` que sirva de "contenedor" (por ejemplo un `ArrayList`) y serializar y deserializar el "contenedor".
- Poner los objetos uno detrás de otro.

  - Para escribir: o bien abrir en modo `append`, o simplemente no abrir y cerrar el `FileOutputStream` y `ObjectOutputStream` para cada objeto.
  - Para leer: Abrir `FileInputStream`, leer un objeto del `ObjectInputStream`, leer el siguiente del `ObjectInputStream`, y así sucesivamente.

Por cierto, `ObjectOutputStream` no serializa mediante cadenas de texto; los ficheros resultantes son binarios.